# admin vs. www-data in running git from php

Tags: php

My PHP runs "exec" under the user "www-data"

my git repository is owned by "admin"

so it cannot access.

If I change ownership to "www-data" it passes the access problem but I can't create SSH keys because www-data is not a "real" user. I don't even know what that is. where is the home folder for such user?

also, when i change the ownership to "www-data" I cannot use git as admin on that machine anymore. gives me `error: cannot open .git/FETCH_HEAD: Permission denied`

1. Where is the home fold for user www-data ?
2. how can I get it to be able to use git with SSH keys set up?

Comment: What about setting the group of the repo to some group which contains admin and www-data and use group based permissions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Transferring ownership to www-data is the right decision. I mean `www-data` is indeed the owner and since it needs full read/write permissions to that folder anyway - do it!.

---

*The following information is at least true for Debian based systems*

`www-data` is a *real* user. Also it has a home dir. You can find it using:

```
cat /etc/passwd | awk -F: '/www-data/{print $6}'
```

On Debian/Ubuntu it is `/var/www` for example.

To make the github access possible you can create keys for `www-data` and place them in `/var/www/.ssh`. **!!!Make sure that this folder is not accessible from web!!!**. Then create a *machine-user* on github add use the public key for www-data.

Creating the keys:

```
sudo -u www-data ssh-keygen -t rsa
```

Once you are finished, create a new user on github, name it `your-app-machine-user` (or whatever), copy `/var/www/.ssh/id_rsa.pub`and add it to that github account.

Read access for www-data should work now.

Comment: did that. i have /var/www/.ssh/id_rsa.pub, created a new deployment key on BitBucket with the content of this key, and yet, i;m getting the same "Host key verification failed." from git.

Comment: Issue the following command: `sudo -u www-data ssh github.com` and confirm the remote host key. This will add github.com's public key to www-data's know_hosts file. After that it should work.

Comment: I am not on getup.com. I'm on Bitbucket. In any case the command yields an error: `sudo: github.com: command not found`

Comment: I missed the 'ssh' the first time I've posted the comment. Check it again. This will work with bitbucket too.

Answer (score 0):

Try: chown -R www-data:www-data .git/